# Не загружается .css Spring Boot + Flying Saucer

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Почему не загружается css при запуске на localhost?

Код отлично работает и шрифт добавляется в другом приложении без spring boot.

Загружаю file.html файл, добавляю в него styles.css со шрифтом times.ttf, чтобы отображались русские символы и превращаю в file.pdf. Я не создаю file.html, поэтому добавляю шрифт через jsoup.

Все решения из подобных вопросов не помогают, добавлял styles.css в папку src/main/resources/static, /public и т.д., указывал всевозможные пути к css в html - я действительно попробовал все варианты. Также пытался загрузить шрифт из кода в flying saucer, этот способ не работает для меня -

```
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("times.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Код

```
public static void label() throws Exception {
    String baseUrl = FileSystems
        .getDefault()
        .getPath("src", "main", "resources")
        .toUri()
        .toURL()
        .toString();
    File inputHTML = new File("file.html");
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(inputHTML, "UTF-8");
    Element table = document.select("head").first();
    table.appendElement("link")
        .attr("href","styles.css")
        .attr("rel","stylesheet")
        .attr("type","text/css");
    document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("file.pdf")) {
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        SharedContext sharedContext = renderer.getSharedContext();
        sharedContext.setPrint(true);
        sharedContext.setInteractive(false);
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(document.html(), baseUrl);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
    }
```

**file.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Маркировочный лист</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    main {
      display: block;
      width: 600px !important;
      margin: 5px auto 0;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    }
    
    table {
      display: table;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      min-width: 600px;
    }
    
    td {
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .first-cell {
      padding: 15px;
      max-width: 308px;
    }
    
    .data-value {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 2px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      line-height: 1;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .trade-name {
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .trade-value {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .brand-text {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    
    .left-side {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .big-size {
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .merchant-user {
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>





  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      window.print();
    }
  </script>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-cell">
          <img style="max-width: 100%" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="trade-name">Номер<br/>доставки:</span><br/><br/><span class="trade-value">834646226</span>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="5" style="padding: 0 5px">
          <div class="brand-text">
            <div><img style="max-width: 60px" src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB8AAAEsCAYAAAA7N2iOAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA
    AARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAp6SURBVHhe7Z3h
    kdS6EkaHW+8/ZABEABkAEUAGQARABCwRsEQARAAZABEAEQARQAZ7dYx7q6enW27J
    nme441OlWo891ie1JXVL9nivXBR2CX79+rV78+bN7suXL7tPnz4Nn0lw7dq13e3b
    t3e3bt3aPXjwYHf37t1h/ySI1/jw4cNFyYwCptONGzcuzs7OLr59+zbm4hOK//z5
    8+LJkydu5tlEIV6/fj3meIhr9u/fv+/u3bs3/LWUDAezYmLMLebXl8Py9OnT3cuX
    L8dPiqEICkxVMj2oxaNHj4ZLMAU1pcbe+ZY9cYTtiXzOiFqeP3++lw/JFmBP3AqX
    Fjxc+14+f/58YMXz8/PxqBLHXPpLc4UFWwC2Jd9LcV1rtqe6SQulsV3mTaIbwiBu
    a82XM5QBZSioJMnUQ48VUvtBXB8gkwy2NlPWevfu3d73hwpzQO/0uoTF6xW1wQSo
    qb726OzoRjoTSjjFw4cP987JFBishf+xI1Ip3bjlg3N5+/bt+On3iFf69PipDqOi
    gO6BOJlF8N0XL16Mn35Txv/qORpdsUF83E7BycXk46ffYAVbgTQ919y62OI4xiN1
    6JpyztBgh/6mMqr1VcFr7XrYjNDnDBXwdmawFqMb1fo5w6z+/jBOcMB6oKwX8waa
    yB/Y7klBB/FhQx3I1h70dSR5fT7KfxAHm0nm2gM1nbr+UaO+FKd0evgjZRoR2OtJ
    Yp9GLpG2zKU4WO9Gylogc/0JSHWj3BMHL/who0wjtI1qqu0ciINXABLRDTWkIF6r
    zlx/jSsOXAKbkZfsZbFth9pH3S8UBzIa/K4S85K9JFiHgk/5+Kq4QCHIiFp44lOj
    W0R6oijgwZid8Fe8Gd6uFGwyFrA0iy9Jkz9fmk18FTbxVWju5x8/fhwGGdKPHz+G
    fQwud+7cGVaiyrA67EuBeAbG72h41QlfkB1qU+I2UJhKOBUbyXhMike+nYSIdp86
    ZZzNpEu1mWJ6G0yI17P+n+/WqIrbsGgqnqMQtgC16VcobmtNaJ2B8/SlqNU+FLfL
    GJkGJOhlUwoSEQ4y9GOBfsyqchYCC4GAw1tGhVBcz7lbhMF+X+elCcWprRCdHJH9
    fkocs7UUQF8yCIfc8dofYOdfmRmLwORCzmM7otrP9Vhey0TD4KO7Wi12r4pTW8kk
    288BQc5hwKHfR1TFgVFuKhMP+vrU4lLKn9PYdANcitOdNIQ1p28TMi1BiW7GLQPi
    HtJil0gRq5p9VfH/jX+rMDbb1WbahKy70w1Z+hbomq9evRo/VRjNf4C+5l40okc/
    BiGNjYIiTvea/5niLZFM77gfiuvow4tkuMskdDudseG5lEwvW6yeANLS9TF7jyXb
    2qviOv6uJS/E0udGVMWpga6hl2wfF/QicERVHAgkJRObiOtqEY4UPiIdTNDAeCAD
    rl69mn4ehvMil3q6kcyq4qHZCaHsHeNeSlcctwyIe2xh1DFJidOfi5X2ku67PLag
    j5XBZTxSZzP7Kvz3xIlsSFMcTZweMMXRzM5zj3aWc0Dply5TMxaCDMInUhRQSDQT
    UXUsMhe7fv367uzsbNhuhchXR8KaLZhYhdDs79+/3z179mz8NI/Q0SDusQUTR2W0
    QAoGE04h1QYP/b2axOma/e8Ur9130fujcR2axMlIBwnRwvD5+fm4VRdvau2g77sw
    92YwEnCh9nZ37bHUZnH8t86cRCHoevy1xyJfD83ioGtfS1N3nbvEMe9UATJPAXeJ
    C1xvCiHmxvQsmXmrUx5bJLMKm/gqnK542M9xi/bxg17KQDRuGRD38BxIb4o43Ws+
    y7Fo8HTebRGcTsQi4ng3L5DAw1GoiFniRCmeX2dfxq12iVMb7wlBak8Ml6VZnMdP
    CBqsMJFLzcQeafG5JvZIi3uDTvZnJhFpcUzqmXtOAZqvOd3KFoLPevKQpVkcuP70
    YV0AEg9v1SYJli5xASEEbSFo+ZlCzBIXei/FIuKCN/BQiIhQfPPnx6Q6V5Mn9+fC
    krnHNlFchdDsLHXpB3HmEN4iQdzjP9/PQ7OzwMf7RaAMkQdTnuI4Lh9d8Y7rSxZI
    xDbRZidUsuA05Dju1SLHSBGn29U28VX4O8XLvGzo2yT95owmxi53wFQ/n4JzJEVs
    /nwVQrOzBsdt7CVo9ufaccxNEX+m2fXTIj1k/PnRutqVK1fGrVj8dLvaJr4KofjU
    7xiWIBRnaL158+bu8ePHw9TpKNDPPezwil9mX3Z9lfUZSRHNYzsryy13imvEo34B
    AYS8hXySLHe1LPxpquICpp7ycj3WSIkLWoxa6896f9Ya3eLAwv/9+/f39uuENbp+
    ee+hM9ZQS2obWSNiEXENNbUNNGIxcRob99W8nhExS5xewN0kBiB9TBIFqf2Auluc
    TKP+z8+KGNmmRsO0OBl5QpKkli19fVKczCKzkjiG6bNjviYURzQyK/tpXK0jmiUU
    94bTObX0mBRfqpYe1UkD87UyRKZ+ItDDNj9fhU18FU5XvLogtNRvGsroOG4ZEPdg
    OOXwEinizzR7z301zvEWkQKJik0aIWzy/H/XRDELbcOL1/H9U7OWbnECCu9hDQqS
    9f1d4kQz1sR8zkSsmiZxaqRfyyQJC/RMk9PiXr9vMbFHup97oVRpVPUfTEwxFiKF
    NxPlM/t76GpwXp+mEC3vkIMucaCBMfnXBSCxL9v4usUF7z0UWCXznNxscaGnPSzq
    WHioxzsnkBgOuHj9ujdF/Ln+fKn3TJTrPm7ts83VDqDV8pwMf4+28I/ZPeifHCYx
    aDBytQ6fU6TEdZKBo8d/W0JxMkfECx4kYY05/jweARSY23MiknqtkRIXPGGbWqzR
    LU4tCSStM5HEfvx+zRrd4hpqWrssEYuIC9JIbZQTsdgIx0DEjcCmfw4zFiIFX5ck
    YHLeD2prK4lpU0S3OI0pamwUJLNk2i3updaF4UlxBhgvVJaUraVHKI4oNfEESa21
    9AjFPccyp5YeKfElaukRhlH0Wdbcy/T34IHapTjdGK5q9u2tKsciNDszFu89Engt
    2V98+PD/GTx4xEUIJCo2CdBBA5cmQr5Tk/gzZyz/D5rFefulEEUstBeh+Pxx65Bm
    cZ3Z169fx619jiZeZjDj1u+BSAsJemmkJt7c2kGHT2zj8XCztH67Er3YczJCdvSj
    YDW6xIHQyhOUhPDU3K1bHDA1jyfp+A5RCpYJPE7Xn68qHpodz7W97/VYNAcTAr9V
    k2G0dK3qMErQ4TLUvwN9WXpnMKuavavmjF56fS4zlHo0iyOCmAjrAtRiOo8mcTK3
    83T7OfOmLCEt7nkx/DiWsEuk2cswKc71tf/2itraFm4Lx3em/t9qVdy7vrVaeZel
    6/1wCNiMCJGm/LRX4IjwCGbVGbS8SYMCsnwyW5zal2F03NuGtIOIqjjmm3tro3Z+
    1bFAKcDw9xisGsOF4szDlrqlFVoPcQ/b2uekiNONXlPirEAWK+2lMpSOR3+HSfZ4
    hs3sq7CJr8LfKc4dCDwfqQSS4942qo6FpS4oAcUg1oJ+BdBpvcaHH0JLitha+yqs
    Kn60GI6fEgthh0LcQy97zE0R2zVfnO1tCzU28RXY7f4FV26MoHx6m8wAAAAASUVO
    RK5CYII=" /> </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-side">Продавец: <span class="merchant-user">ООО "КОНТИ"</span></td>
        <td class="right-side" rowspan="2">
          <span class="trade-name">Номер<br/>отправления:</span><br/><br/><span style="font-size: 24px">868140708</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-side">ID продавца: <span>241</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="left-side">Адрес: <span>г Москва, р-н Марфино, ул Академика Комарова, д 1, кв. 1</span></td>
        <td class="right-side" rowspan="2">
          <span class="trade-name">Дата<br/>отгрузки:</span><br/><br/><span style="font-size: 24px">06.09.2021</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-side">ФИО: <span>Милешин Олег</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**styles.css:**

```css
@font-face {
  src: local('Times New Roman'), url('times.ttf');
  -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
  -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

body {
  font-family: Times New Roman, Arial, verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 8.8pt;
}
```

**основные зависимости gradle:**

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.6"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.5.6"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.5.6"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.6"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:2.5.6"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.6"
implementation 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.1.22'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.15.3'
```

**Main.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Main {
  public void start(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().start(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Я вообще не вижу ссылку на css в вашем html.

Comment: @МихаилРебров css добавляется через jsoup, потому что не я создаю html

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rClNZLXSKA8/mqdefault.jpg

Comment: @МихаилРебров html приходит по http и я добавляю ссылку на css с шрифтом, который должен отображаться в pdf файле. В закрепе html БЕЗ моих изменений. Повторюсь: КОД РАБОТАЕТ и я не прошу комментариев по его реализации и прочего. Я пытаюсь разобраться только с загрузкой css в Spring Boot. Если вам нечего сказать по делу - не тратьте ни моё, ни своё время.

Comment: А вы не думали, дорогой мой, что я не просто так спросил про ссылку на css. Как вам отвечать когда ее нет и когда непонятно какой запрос и куда отправляется?.. Это вы тратите чужое время . мне есть что сказать по делу. Я уже на десятки подобных вопросов ответил

Comment: С какой стати спрингу вообще ваш css файл где то возвращать? Вы можете ответить на этот вопрос? Где вы это настраивали?

Comment: @МихаилРебров вы хорошо себя чувствуете?! Вы вообще смотрели на код, видели, что ссылка на css добавляется?! table.appendElement("link")
        .attr("href","styles.css")
        .attr("rel","stylesheet")
        .attr("type","text/css"); - это что? Да, я добавил сам html без css, чтобы было наглядно, как он мне приходит, но если бы вы прочитали вопрос, то увидели бы, что там про это всё описано. По поводу второго комментария: это я и пытаюсь узнать, как мне настроить спринг.

Comment: @МихаилРебров P.S. Очень рад, что вы «ответили» на десятки подобных вопросов, на мой не ответили. Но если у вас всегда такая токсичная манера общения, «отвечайте» другим, я обойдусь без вашего ценного мнения))

Comment: Я себя чувствую прекрасно. Спасибо за заботу. Вы задаете вопрос без деталей не прикладывая ни адрес по которому вы ожидаете увидеть данный css, ни расположение данного css в рамках проекта, ни конфигурации MVC и с кодом, который к заданному вами вопросу вообще никак не относится. В ответ на наводящие вопросы человека, который мог бы вам помочь вы начинаете язвить, а виноват в итоге я...замечательно!

Comment: Я смотрел ваш код... и что с того что вы добавляете этот тег в JSoup?.. вы можете мне сказать где его будет искать iText, для которого это просто кусок html никаким образом не привязанный ни к какому url?

Comment: в вашем случае не на localhost его нужно искать а добавлять resolver аналогичный тому, что вы делали для шрифта https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/faq/how-to-add-external-css-while-generating-pdf  localhost вам в таком случае вообще не нужен

Comment: в вашем посте 2 несвязанных между собой вопроса. И вам нужно было спрашивать не как сделать доступным `.css` в localhost, а как его добавить в iText...и Spring с localhost тут вообще не при чем

Comment: @МихаилРебров Удивительно, но вы действительно подсказали, в каком направлении мне двигаться - за это спасибо. 
Впредь, если не нравится вопрос, можете пройти мимо, а если вы решили меня жизни научить, то поубавьте своё эго)) 
Буду рад, если вы больше не напишите сюда - это утомляет. Всего хорошего.

Comment: вы неисправимый человек. Я вам помогал с самого начала. И это Ваше же эго мешало вам получить ответ на вопрос быстрее.